# org.renjin.eval.EvalException: Could not load package org.renjin.cran:parallel

Tags: java, r, parallel-processing, package, renjin

When I am trying to run a R script in my Java web application using Renjin 
I am getting an exception-

**org.renjin.eval.EvalException: Could not load package org.renjin.cran:parallel** .

I'am not able to find the 'parallel' package in Renjin website. Can anyone suggest me how to solve it?

Comment: Did the answer below help or are you still stuck?

Answer (score 0):

If you upgrade to the latest version of Renjin (0.8.1915) this should now work. The parallel package is part of the R distribution so you should not need any additional dependencies.

However, at the moment, Renjin's implementation of the parallel package is just a spike to get things working: we don't yet have any backends for actually parallelizing the work.

If you run into any problems with the current version of Renjin, don't hesitate to open a bug report at https://github.com/bedatadriven/renjin.

Note that Renjin *is* able to automatically parallelize many R scripts. See the [MultiThreadedVectorPipeliner](https://github.com/bedatadriven/renjin/blob/a26364e00785c83633a12aab74d29c50c89eef52/core/src/main/java/org/renjin/compiler/pipeline/MultiThreadedVectorPipeliner.java) for more information on configuring a custom thread pool, etc for your webapp.